# ASP.Net core + wind auth + custom roles: "The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using windows authentication, plus a custom `IClaimsTransformation` where I look up the username in the database to retrieve some custom roles, and add to the identity like so:

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "MyRole"));
```

At the top of my controllers I have `[Authorize(Roles = "MyRole")]` but when I access a page I get the following error message:

> The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed

(It works if I comment out the [Authorize] line, but this is not a solution of course).

My Startup.cs looks something like this:-

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    services.AddAuthorization();

    services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, ApplicationClaimsTransformer>();

    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong? My role names are not AD roles - just arbitrary strings within my application (which I suspect is the problem), so how can I get this working?

**EDIT**

I've found that if I return a GenericPrincipal from my custom claims transformer, then this seems to fix the problem. Not sure if it's the "proper" way of doing things, or if this may come back and bite me in the future?

```
public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
    var username = identity.Name;

    var rolenames = ... Look up role names from the database ...

    var genIdentity = new GenericIdentity(username);
    var genPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(genIdentity, rolenames);

    return Task.FromResult(new ClaimsPrincipal(genPrincipal));
}
```

Comment: Is there any "proper" way to fix this problem? Did you encounter any problems later on?

Comment: @kkamil4sz no it seemed to work fine with no apparent bad effects since!

Comment: @kkamil4sz I used this solution and while it worked great it baited me back when trying to RunImpersonated() becuase casting a GenericPrincipal to a WindowIdentity can't be done. I need to run some methods impersonating the user WindowIdentity so I had to change approach. Adding a new Identity to the principal with my custom Claims solved the cast issue and User.IsInRole stopped returning always "false".
The Roles problem is solved, some problems with RunImpersonated (getting ACCESS DENIED when published to IIS, everything fine while testing on my machine). Will update.

Comment: It seems like a good solution, works as a charm for me. Could you please write your own answer for better legibility? @AndrewStephens

Answer (score 2):

As requested by @torendil, I have moved the "edit" out of my question and into an answer:-

I've found that if I return a GenericPrincipal from my custom claims transformer, then this seems to fix the problem. Not sure if it's the "proper" way of doing things, or if this may come back and bite me in the future?

```
public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
    var username = identity.Name;

    var rolenames = ... Look up role names from the database ...

    var genIdentity = new GenericIdentity(username);
    var genPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(genIdentity, rolenames);

    return Task.FromResult(new ClaimsPrincipal(genPrincipal));
}
```